# Capybara "fill_in" by xpath?

Tags: automation, capybara

I'm running into some trouble attempting to `fill_in` a Text form on a form group.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-filter="0">
</div>
```

I've tried using fill_in via using the label text IE "First Name" with no luck; I've also tried using the "data-filter="0"" with no luck (I'm not even sure what this is; it doesn't seem to be an id of any sort).

I figured maybe I could use the xpath? but can you even do a finder on the xpath of something and then fill it in? I couldn't find anything that seemed to reference being able to in the capybara module docs.

Comment: The reason the label text doesn't work is because the label isn't tied to the input in any way - it would need to either have a `for` attribute whose value would be the `id` of the input (if there was one), or it would need to wrap the input to tie it to the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `find` and `set`:

```
find(:xpath, "//label[text()='First Name']/following-sibling::input").set("text")
```

Or:

```
find(:xpath, "//div[label='First Name']/input").set("text")
```

Comment: Im confused about the following-sibling thing, i've never seen that in Capybara before?

Comment: @msmith1114 Thats an XPath expression being used to find the element and then calling `set` on it.

Comment: @msmith1114, the `following-sibling` is an axis of the XPath: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/. You could also use `//div[label='First Name']/input`